# How to make a div inside a div move as I scroll?

Tags: css

My first idea was to put `position: fixed`, but when I do that, the inner div just disappears. It's not hidden behind anything else either, because I have tried changing the distance from the top.

Here is my code:

```css
#menu {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  order: 1;
}
    
#menu #buttons {
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Now, that bigger div is an element within a flexbox, which is also a div. I hope that isn't the source of the problem, but if there is no other way of fixing it, I would change that setup. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you test things, mind to set some content inside your tags, else they might not show up at all. empty div is height:0; width:100% emty div fixed is height:0 & width : 0.  Your snippet doesn't show much of your trouble. I did not really understood what you try to do

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `overflow-y: scroll` for the inner div. Also mind that the outer div should be use `position: fixed` And it's better to use `width: 100%` for the inner div.

In addition, You should fill the inner div with some content Unless it wont be shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```css
#menu {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

#buttons {
    background-color: black;
     width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 15px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div id="buttons"></div>
</div>
```